# javascript alert issue after page close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using onbeforeunload function to alert the user before he closes his browser window. Currently the alert will be called if we close any tab of the browser.

I just need this functionality to be:

1) Alert before only when our tab is trying to close, ie this alert will not show when we try to close other tabs.

2) Should show when we try to close the whole browser using close button top right-end corner..

the below code works with jquery, th only problem that I am now facing  in Mozilla firefox is, if there is any links present in that page like href to www.google.com, it will show the alert...in that case also, which is not needed. This works in IE, I am using mozilla 3.6

Please help.....

code below

```
<html>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {
      return "Are you sure?"
    });
  });

</script>

<body>
hiiiiii


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You already asked me this question. Another alternative functions do not exist except onbeforeunload.

Comment: Uhm... I tried that code in Firefox 3.6xxxx too and it works as expected... perhaps there are other specific issue w/ the browser that you are using... hmmm.

Comment: I wonder how it works for you...the only issue is if there any hyperlinks(external links to google/yahoo), this alert will come at that time also...I need to avoid this...Is it possible? Can u please share the code worked for you...

Comment: please help this is urgent...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly, there is no information in the `event object` (not yet). So you don't know how the user wants to leave your page. But you could work around this issues. For instance, you want to allow all `external links` to leave your site, you add some boolean flag.

```
var allowunload = false;


$('a').bind('click', function() {
    allowunload = true;
});
```

...And check for that in the `beforeunload` event:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    if(!allowunload)
        return 'sure?';
});
```

See this in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/41/

Comment: hi Jandy, If a user clicks any link, it should go to that page as normal without any alert...alert should happen only when he tries to close his tab and not other tabs..and also if he tries to close the whole browser using 'close' button in top-right-end of browser...hope I have put sufficient info for you..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
   return 'sure?';
});
```

This will unbind the event if the user clicks on an anchor. It has a small side effect though, if the anchor doesn't redirect to another page, but instead does some JavaScript functionality.